# MySql subquery with count and order by RAND() across 2 tables

Tags: mysql, nested

I am trying to combine two tasks into a single query...and running into trouble.  Lets assume 2 tables "users" and "assignments" each containing a UserId field.  In the "assignments" table, there might be multiple rows with the same "UserId" field, so it has a key of unique pairings between "UserId" and "TeammateId".

```
+--------------+
+-----users----+
+--------------+
+-UserId(pk)---+
+-UserName-----+
+----(etc...)--+


+---------------+
+--assignments--+
+---------------+
+-UserId--------+
+-TeammateId----+
+----(etc...)--+
```

The TeammateId is populated with userId of other possible users with the goal of making team groupings.

```
UserId 1 = Joe
UserId 2 = Sally
UserId 3 = Hank
UserId 4 = Wanda
```

My end goal is to populate the assignments table to look like this:

```
+--UserId--+--TeammateId--+
+-- 1 -----+-- 4 ---------+
+-- 1 -----+-- 2 ---------+
+-- 2 -----+-- 1 ---------+
+-- 2 -----+-- 3 ---------+
+-- 3 -----+-- 1 ---------+
+-- 3 -----+-- 4 ---------+
+-- 4 -----+-- 2 ---------+
+-- 4 -----+-- 3 ---------+
```

So team leader Joe has been assigned 2 teammates, Wanda and Sally.  You will notice that each UserId has two TeammateIds assigned to it...and they are not the same as the UserId (you can't be on your own team).  Furthermore, each TeammateId is used not more than 2 times. (yes, this means that essentially there are three teams per user, but in each case my initial UserId is a team leader and is assigned 2 partners).

My plan is to use PHP to run a query for each UserId to generate the 2 teammates...which then should ideally return two random TeammateId numbers that are valid (as in, do not = the user, each other, or already used 2 times).

Assuming we run this script for Wanda (user 4), the initial query might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `UserId` != '4' ORDER BY RAND();
```

this gives me the data I need (UserId, UserName, and a few other fields) for an initial set of possible Teammates in a random order.

My PHP option is to then parse these results one row at a time, looking for any where SELECT COUNT(teammate)<2 and UserId!='4' and once I find that, then I have one result...and I just loop a second time for a second result.

This requires that each query be run 3 times per user...which would be okay (fairly small data set and not much traffic)...but I know there must be a way to do this all as a single (nested probably) query that will just generate my 2 teammates in a single step.

Here is a sqlfiddle for testing:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae736f

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. With reference to that link, obviously, for your desired result, you can only provide 1 or 2 allowable results.

Comment: @Strawberry I am pretty sure I have provided sample data, desired results, and relevant table structures, as well as an example of what I have done thusfar that would accomplish this solution as a workaround, just not in the best possible ideal way.

Comment: "you can't be on your own team", but only because you chose to have a user_id column instead of a team_id column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it!  Can anyone tell me how this can be improved?

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE `UserId` != '4' 
AND `UserId` NOT IN 

(  SELECT `TeammateId`
FROM `assignments`
GROUP BY `TeammateId`
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2  ) 

ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
```